# SSH cannot authenticate to git@github.com

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

Recently, I sign up for a free plan on Github.com.
I follow their instructions to generate a ssh key to add to my account.
However, when I try `ssh -v git@github.com`, I get this error:

```
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Trying private key: /home/phuongnd08/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/phuongnd08/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

When I look into the error, I see a funny thing here, that is the .ssh/id_rsa was not tried, just .ssh/identity and .ssh/id_dsa were tried.

How can I fix this error?
Thanks

Comment: Check the file permissions on your key.  If they are too liberal it may be refusing to use the key.  Make sure they only have perssion for you (0700).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the problems. Why don't you post your word as an answer?

Comment: Made my comment an answer.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the file permissions on your key. If they are too liberal it may be refusing to use the key. Make sure they only have perssion for you (0700).

Comment: Executing `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` essentially changes the file permission on `id_rsa` to 700 (by giving the authentication agent a private key identity). Refer the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add) page.

Answer (score 137):

You can use `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @hailor. This was giving me quite a bit of trouble.

Comment: This worked but I have no idea what I just did, can someone explain his?

Comment: I anyone is still curious, here's an explanation of what `ssh-add` does: http://askubuntu.com/a/137167/14564

Comment: worked for me as well, and thanks Sergey for the additional info regarding ssh-add!

Comment: This just have happened to me when there was a previous key in the .ssh/ folder. It should be included in the instructions of github when you backup a previous ssh key...

Comment: WOW. This one works though I don't quite understand. Previously lost my passphrase, then I changed my private key..

Answer (score 8):

After trying all these answers with no luck, the following command solved it for me:

`unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK`

Comment: It seems like there is a problem with the ssh that it uses gui to ask and then store the passwords in memory, there is probably bug that if the password for the key is not present it will wait for the input but the input is not prompted to the user.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't already exist, you generate the ssh key first:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

now copy this key, it'll be in this dir ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub,
open with notepad,
paste this key in the "add ssh key" section  in your github account!
That's it!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Github enterprise** (Self hosting) it would be worth checking to see if the site is reachable. Applies to Github also.

Ran into the same issue in Intellij and when I went to check if the RSA public key was saved in my profile I found out the site returned a server error.