# Issue with SSH key setup while setting up github

Tags: git, version-control, github, ssh-keys, permission-denied

I followed [this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) tutorial to generate SSH key on github: 
At step number 5 of the above linked tutorial,after I type `ssh -T git@github.com` I am supposed to see this:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
# RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
# Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I, however, see this:

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Then later when I tried to push a file to repository using `git push -u origin master`, I get this:

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I think the problem is with the set up of SSH key.
How can I get solve this problem?

I am using Linux.

Comment: have you entered the SSH key in Account Settings-> SSH Key, make sure you haven't modify is

Comment: which os are you using??

Comment: @NixitPatel I am on Linux - Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @NixitPatel and yes I have entered SSH key to account. and the two keys(the one in my computer and my account) match.

Comment: might you have already checked it but, make sure your public key have full permission. or other thing you can do is delete the existing key and try regenerate it.

Comment: @NixitPatel Although, restarting the computer got rid of the issue but jut one more thing: What do you mean when you say "make sure your public key have full permission" ?

Comment: it means linux user have permission to access , read and write to the public key:- id_rsa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After googleing I found that most possible chances is that your key is corrupt.

and the things that you can try is...

and `ssh-add` is also the one which has solve the problem of lots of people `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

try logout and login
or

hear is few more things that you can try http://sampathm.blogspot.in/2011/06/agent-admitted-failure-to-sign-using.html
and 
[SSH cannot authenticate to git@github.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122465/ssh-cannot-authenticate-to-gitgithub-com)
hope this help

Comment: Restarting the computer seems to do the trick! Thanks for your help!